e: type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list e: the list of sources could not be read
Got this error. It says type '"deb is not know 1 line etc. How to resolve this? Im new pls explain to me well

There is an error in line 1 of the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list. So the obvious question is, what does that line say? Edit your question and let us see what that file looks like.

Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please edit your question and add the exact content of the file that's mentioned in the error message. There's probably a syntax error somewhere in that file. Preferrably, use the code formatting to make the code easier to read.

e: type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list                                      e: the list of sources could not be read. this is the error. actually sir it's the same on some question here but the problem i cant understand some answer sir because im newbie

Then your question needs to clearly tell us what you don't understand. Is there a word or phrase that is confusing to you? Is there a translation  issue? Are you asking for more detailed instructions with a specific step? Edit your question to help us help you. This error is almost always self-inflicted.

yes sir i need specific steps sir. done editing sir.

i dont know what happened because i have another vps and i successfully done the node there then i buy another vps for another node then always error , says e: type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
e: the list of sources could not be read.

Did you look at that line of that file on that system?

sir where can i see the file in the system? or how can i see it? i dont know sir have a patience on me

it's the same on others problem but i dont get the answer there.  it says " Run sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list, remove the " at the beginning of the first line, save and close. All done." but how can i delete " in the first line if in my putty the result there are like this "~ ~~~~ 0, 0-1      All"

It seems you need some help with basic commands. To view the contents of that particular file, do cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list. Then paste the contents of that file into your question (don't leave it as a comment). To change the contents, you can use sudoedit. The contents of the file will start with deb (as the error message says) so the first line cannot be ~ ~~~~ 0, 0-1 All as you say.

Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T.
Run it:
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

In the archive open, in line 1 (which contains the error) write # at the beginning of the text.
Save the archive by pressing Ctrl + O
Close nano, pressing Ctrl + X
Close the terminal.
The lines that fill with # are commented lines, the system to see these symbols at the beginning of the line tells you that the next one is not necessary and jumps to the next line that does not fill for this sign.
